# How to disable spell checking on custom Android Keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, spell-checking, ime, android-input-method

I have been building relatively simple Android Keyboard from ground up following this [Android SoftKeyboard sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/). I can't seem to find any solution that would allow me to disable spell-checking functionality with my custom keyboard. Every text typed has a black underline indicating possible spell error even though I have not implemented spell-checking services.

Tried to find appropriate code fragment that disables spell-checking in [Android/LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) but in vain.

Any tips are highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black underline is called composing text.  Its used to show text that may be replaced by an autocorrect or other action-  it isn't fully finished text yet.  Its done by calling setComposingText.  Instead of using that, use commitText and it won't use the underline version (and a dozen other differences under the hood).

Note that if you're exactly following the linked code you'll have to make a lot of other changes too, to move from word at a time to letter at a time input (composing text is completely replaced each time a new input is made, so you need to send down the entire word until you commitText of complete the composing text.  SO you probably have a but of work to change it to use commitText).

Comment: Thank you! Lifesaver, you are!